# Fail to install cloud docker environment

Tags: magento2.4, cloud-docker

I try to build Magento 2.4.5 with php 8.1 docker on premises environment and I followed the process described here https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-installation.html.

I ended up with error:

> Cannot decode string: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ERROR: 1

Below are the exact steps I followed with the exact commands:

1. Created project using composer

   `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.5 magento-community-edition`
2. Change to directory magento-community-edition
3. Add the ece-tools and Cloud Docker for Commerce packages.

   `composer require --no-update --dev magento/ece-tools magento/magento-cloud-docker`
4. Install ece tools and cloud docker with composer

   `compose update`
5. I ran the Docker configuration generator and created docker-compose.yml

   `./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --mode=production --php=8.1 --db=10.3`
6. Created and started containers

   `./bin/magento-docker up`
7. Run build hooks

   `./bin/magento-docker ece-build`

At this step after it run installing various composer dependencies if fails with error:

> Running "build" hook. Cannot decode string: list indices must be
> integers or slices, not str ERROR: 1

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi!

Did you create the `.magento.app.yaml` file?

Also, you can try to use the template for 2.4.5: https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/tree/2.4.5

Templates contain all needed config files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the `.magento.app.yaml` file but still same problem. I cannot use above repository because I try the community edition.

Answer (score 0):

try these steps:

- clone needed branch from https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud
- run `composer install`
- run `./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose`
- run `docker-compose up -d`
- run `docker-compose run build cloud-build`
- run `docker-compose run deploy cloud-deploy`
- run `docker-compose run deploy cloud-post-deploy`